# Is it possible to have wild meat inspected or graded?

Tags: hunting

Is there any way to get wild meat inspected and graded in the same (or similar) way as domestic meats for parasites, contaminants, etc.?  If so what are good starting resources or methods for finding a local source for grading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that there is a way to get your wild game graded.

> As allowed by law, for field-dressed wild game animals under a routine inspection program that ensures the animals:
>
> (a) Receive a postmortem examination by an approved veterinarian or veterinarian's designee, or
> (b) Are field-dressed and transported according to requirements specified by the agency that has animal health jurisdiction and the agency that conducts the inspection program, and
> (c) Are processed according to laws governing meat and poultry as determined by the agency that has animal health jurisdiction and the agency that conducts the inspection program.

From the 2009 FDA [website](http://www.fda.gov/Food/FoodSafety/RetailFoodProtection/FoodCode/FoodCode2009/ucm186451.htm).